# need to display selected Values through javascript

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery

My VF page is something like this

```
<apex:page standardController="Temporary_Contact__c" extensions="tempView" >
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jquery)}"/>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function onCheck(){
      var rowvalues=$(".rowOrder").val();
      alert(rowvalues);
    }  
    </script>

    <apex:form >
         <apex:pageblock > 
             <apex:variable value="0" var="rowOrder"/>
             <apex:pageblocktable value="{!convalues}" var="con" columns="9">        
                <apex:column headerValue="Sno:">
                   {!con.viewContact__c}
                 </apex:column>
                 <apex:column headervalue="Action">                      
                     <apex:inputcheckbox value="{!con.Check_temp__c}"/>
                 </apex:column>
                  <apex:column headerValue="Order Number">
                     {!con.OrderNumber__c}
                 </apex:column>
                 <apex:column headerValue="First Name">
                     <apex:outputfield value="{!con.First_Name__c}"/>
                 </apex:column>
             <apex:column > <apex:variable value="{!VALUE(rowOrder)+1}" var="rowOrder"></apex:variable> </apex:column>                                        
             </apex:pageblocktable>  
             {!rowOrder}
              <type input="hidden" value="{!rowOrder}" name="rowOrder" class="rowOrder"/> 
             <apex:pageblockbuttons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Process" action="{!ProcessButton}" onclick="if(!onCheck()){return false;}"/>
             </apex:pageblockbuttons>      
         </apex:pageblock>
     </apex:form> 
    </apex:page>
```

[image: Result]

now when I select checkbox the selected checkbox order number should display in my javascript. Can someone help me in this

Answer (score 0):

If i am understanding this correctly :

You can pass the order number on the click event of your checkbox like this :

```
<apex:inputcheckbox value="{!con.Check_temp__c}" onclick="onCheck('{!con.OrderNumber__c}')"/>
```

and then print the passed order number like :

```
 function onCheck(val){    
      alert(val);
    }
```

Comment: it worked well.But i need to keep this onclick in my Process Button.So when I click Process, all the selected checkbox order Number will be displayed.Help me in this

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure *why* you want to achieve this.  What is the purpose of alerting out all checked rows?  You must have some greater goal you are trying to accomplish.

As for a solution, lets add some data to the checkbox:

```
<apex:inputcheckbox value="{!con.Check_temp__c}" styleClass="to-check" label="{!rowOrder}" />
```

Now lets change up the javascript:

```
<script>
  function onCheck() {
    $('input.to-check:checked').each(function(idx, ele) {
      alert($(ele).attr('label'));
    });
  }
</script>
```

In a strange move salesforce added custom html attributes to outputPanels only.  It would be great if all visualforce components had them, then I wouldnt have to misuse the label attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the selected items in an array by adding and removing them dynamically when the checkboxes are checked or unchecked.

You can use the following piece of code for the "Process" button's onclick event:

```
function checkAndAdd(array, item) {

    //Fetching the index of the item
    var itemIndex = array.indexOf(item);

    //Check if the item is present in the array already
    if(itemIndex > -1) {

        //Remove the existing item from the array
        array.splice(itemIndex, 1);
    }
    else {

        //Add the new item to the array
        array.push(item);
    }
    //alert("Array items: " + array);
}
```

After clicking "Process" button, you can process the items in a for each loop or something like that..

Hope I answered your question.